# Apache Batik Conversion SVG To PDF Not Formatting Text Style

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-generation, batik

Am trying to convert my svg file to pdf. Following is the svg code :

[image: SVG XML Code]

The text formatting is working perfect on Firefox and just fine on chrome browser. 
But the text format code  : `style="text-anchor :middle; dominant-baseline: middle; font-family:Arial;"` doesn't work with apache batik at all.

Although, giving **fixed coordinates** works fine.

PDF output :

[image: PDF output]

Firefox output :

[image: Firefox output]

Any way out to solve this? Thanks.